# Android : post request with Retrofix

Tags: android, retrofit

I use retrofix request data, but the results showed the wrong key

post url:[http://op.juhe.cn/189/bus/station?dtype=json&city=佛山&station=祖庙&key=b7f4857671be4512300c0f52774e5a3c](http://op.juhe.cn/189/bus/station?dtype=json&city=%E4%BD%9B%E5%B1%B1&station=%E7%A5%96%E5%BA%99&key=b7f4857671be4512300c0f52774e5a3c).

My HTTP API into a Java interface:

```
public interface Api {
@POST("bus/station")
Call<Result> check(@Body UrlParam param);
```

}

My MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
@BindView(R.id.bnt01)
Button btn01;
@BindView(R.id.tv01)
TextView tv01;
private Api api;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    btn01.setOnClickListener(this);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://op.juhe.cn/189/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

}

private UrlParam getUrlParam() {
    UrlParam param = new UrlParam("json", "佛山", "祖庙", "b7f4857671be4512300c0f52774e5a3c");
    return param;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bnt01:
            UrlParam p = getUrlParam();
            Call<Result> re = api.check(getUrlParam());
            Log.i("TAG", re.toString() + "//" + api.toString());
            re.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                    tv01.setText(response.body().getReason());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is Result model code:

```
  public class Result {
  private String reason;
  private DetailParam result;
  private String errorCode;

public Result(String errorCode, DetailParam result, String reason) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.result = result;
    this.reason = reason;
}

public String getReason() {
    return reason;
}

public void setReason(String reason) {
    this.reason = reason;
}

public DetailParam getDetail() {
    return result;
}

public void setDetail(DetailParam result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new Gson().toJson(this);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? I can click above link, I think I 's **GET** method, not **POST** method. Can you post your `Result` model

Comment: yes, Can I use the get and post, can also be used but I want to use the post to try. I had post Result model

Comment: if you want to use **POST** with **@body**, your server must support that. Now I see your link, it supports `GET` and `@Query` param

Comment: The server support?Mean, I post a class object on the client, the server will accept a class object

Comment: Correct. WHen you want use `POST` and `BODY`, the server need use POST, and use body object. Now,the server use get and query param

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would recommend changing your retrofit interface to following.

```
public interface Api { 
@POST("bus/station") 
Call<Result> check(@Query("dtype") String dtype, @Query("city") String city, @Query("station") String station, @Query("key") String key);
}
```

Comment: If I want to use @ body to do it, then how should do

Comment: Why do you want to use @Body?